# Apache IVY error message? : impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded

Tags: java, scala, maven, ivy, sbt

hey all, I'm getting the following error when trying to build a project via SBT in scala

```
[info] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts 
    when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = log4j#log4j;1.2.14
```

I don't see any of my projects referencing 1.2.14, nor is it in my .m2 or .ivy repositories. Not sure where to look for this one

a full error dump is here: http://pastebin.com/pM7NUhY0

thanks

Comment: One of your dependencies might be depending on log4j 1.2.14 transitively. Are you able to specify the log4j dependency directly in your project and force Ivy to download it?

Comment: when ivy says "use verbose or debug level" then it really means it as the errors it produces at normal logging levels are pretty obtuse.

Comment: Binil, that's what fixed it. If I manually add the log4 1.2.14 dependency it works, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Seems that this is related to [IVY-987](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-987) and should be fixed in ivy 2.1.0-RC1.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this recently with a junit dependency and it kind of drove me nuts trying to fix it. In my case I had to remove the "test" scope from the dependency declaration (in this case in SBT with Scala).

Anyway, hope it helps someone.

Comment: A better solution for SBT is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13073189/42198