# IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded for Guava 12.0?

Tags: sbt, ivy, playframework-2.1

In a Java Play 2.1.1 app I get the following error:

```
[myproject] $ update
[info] Updating {file:/C:/path/myproject/}myproject...
[info] Resolving ...
[error] impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = com.google.guava#guava;12.0
[error] (*:update) java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = com.google.guava#guava;12.0
[error] Total time: 230 s, completed 17.05.2013 19:16:41
```

**Build.scala**

```
"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "14.0.1",
"org.mydependency" % "mydependency" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT" changing() exclude("org.jboss.netty","netty") exclude("com.google.guava", "guava") exclude("log4j", "log4j"),
```

The thing that causes this error (it all worked fine before) is a dependency change within mydependency:

old:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
    <artifactId>titan-berkeleyje</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

new:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
    <artifactId>titan-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't want guava 12.0 anyway and it is and was excluded.

Can I tell Play 2.1.1 to use a newer Ivy?

In **plugins.sbt** I have:

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.1")
```

**Temporary fix**
As someone mentioned here [Apache IVY error message? : impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158192/apache-ivy-error-message-impossible-to-get-artifacts-when-data-has-not-been-l) manually adding the dependency solves it: I've added

```
"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "12.0"
```

and the problem is gone.

Comment: I just ran into this one when I added a dependency that tries to transitively pull in *slf4j-api;1.6.1* when my project already includes *slf4j-api;1.7.5*.  I worked around it by making said dependency `intransitive()`.

Comment: @gonfi-den-tschal Does the issue exist still?

Comment: Others still seem to have the issue. I have not come across it anymore, but then I'm still using the temporary fix. I have not touched this project nor upgraded Play in a while.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I have had this issue with sbt 0.13.5 (commons-io 2.2 in my case)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently more people had and have this issue, so I'm putting my solution as an answer:

**Temporary fix**
As someone mentioned here [Apache IVY error message? : impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158192/apache-ivy-error-message-impossible-to-get-artifacts-when-data-has-not-been-l) manually adding the dependency solves it: I've added

```
"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "12.0"
```

and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using a lower version, you could try adding this line to .sbt file:

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "14.0.1"
```

Answer (score 4):

Play 2.1.x uses sbt 0.12, which uses Ivy 2.3.0-rc1, but looks like this is still an issue.
If you can come up with a reproduction steps using publicly available libraries, please open a Github issue with a link to this comment.