# Error with Ivy: sbt assembly java.lang.AssertionError java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: sbt, ivy, sbt-assembly, java

I installed spark 1.6.0, java 1.8.0_73 and sbt 0.13.9 on my Mac (El Capitan)

When I type `sbt assembly` I get the following error.

```
[error] (sql/compile:compile) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: List(object package$DebugNode, object package$DebugNode)
[error] (hive/*:update) java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3
[error] Total time: 108 s, completed Feb 15, 2016 3:47:40 PM
```

I looked into this error and it seems that dependency list has something to do with it. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Specifically, do I need to edit the sbt dependency list? If so, which file would it be and how should I edit it?

Per Eugene's request, I am including the following files. If I got the wrong build file, please be patient (I am new here) and let me know which file(s) I should be posting. I appreciate the help!

build.sbt

```
name := "sbt-pom-reader"

organization := "com.typesafe.sbt"

sbtPlugin := true

publishMavenStyle := false

libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.pluginDependencies

git.baseVersion := "1.0"

versionWithGit

scriptedLaunchOpts <+= version apply { v => "-Dproject.version="+v }

initialCommands :=
  """| import com.typesafe.sbt.pom._
     | import sbt._
     | val localRepo = file(sys.props("user.home")) / ".m2" / "repository"
     | val pom = loadEffectivePom(localRepo, file("src/sbt-test/simple-pom/can-extract-basics/pom.xml"))
     |""".stripMargin


scriptedSettings

scriptedLaunchOpts <+= version apply { v => "-Dproject.version="+v }

publishTo <<= (version) { v =>
  def scalasbt(repo: String) = ("scalasbt " + repo, "http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-" + repo)
  val (name, repo) = if (v.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) scalasbt("snapshots") else scalasbt("releases")
  Some(Resolver.url(name, url(repo))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns))
}
```

Comment: There seems to be multiple reports on this especially around Spark. Could you share your build file to [#2015](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2015) or post any reproduction steps to it so I can look into this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16614794/3827

Comment: @EugeneYokota. I read both links, which is where I got the idea that dependencies could be causing this error. I did not think mine was the same error though, however, since mine was caused during `sbt assembly`. I posted my build.sbt here and will do the same on [#2015](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2015)